# matrix multiplication for integral types using BLAS

Tags: matrix, integer, multiplication, blas

Is there an equivalent of dgemm (from BLAS) for integral types?
I only know of dgemm, sgemm for double precision / single precision matrices, but would like to have it for matrices that are of integral type such as int (or short int...).

Note: I'm not looking for a solution that involves converting to float/double, and am looking for a fast library implementation.

Also, same question for dgemms (using strassen algorithm).

Answer (score 4):

BLAS algorithms don't natively support integer types.

Comment: That's what I suspected, but is there any other library to do this? Even a naive implementation on unisgned chars without overflow checking is ~10 times slower than  dgemm using doubles. I'd hope there would be a way to 1) avoid memory+time bottleneck involved in converting to intermediate floating point types.

Comment: http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1073899&dl=GUIDE&coll=GUIDE&CFID=64924169&CFTOKEN=87018353

This is a link to some research published by acm on exact linear algebra for blas.  You might query the authors on how to get the libraries they developed.

Answer (score 3):

You did not specify a programming language. In C++, you could interface with a matrix library such as [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) (disclaimer: I'm associated with this project). Eigen uses vectorization so it should be pretty fast - make sure you [enable vectorization](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=FAQ#Vectorization) - but I didn't do any experiments so I'm not sure. There are some complicated [alignment issues](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/UnalignedArrayAssert.html) that may be a problem for you, but I'm not familiar with them.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380371/what-are-the-most-widely-used-c-vector-matrix-math-linear-algebra-libraries-an) discusses various C++ matrix libraries, mainly in the context of computer graphics.

Comment: But does eigen support integer matrix arithmetic?