# sparse matrix library for C++

Tags: matrix, sparse-matrix, numerical-methods, numerical-analysis

Is there any sparse matrix library that can do these:

- solve linear algebraic equations
- support operations like matrix-matrix/number multiplication/addition/subtraction,matrix transposition, get a row/column of a matrix,and so on
- matrix size could be 40k*40k or bigger,like 250k*250k
- fast
- can be used in Windows

Can someone recommend some libraries for me?
If you recommend, please tell me the advantages and disadvantages of it, and the reason why you recommend  it.

By the way,I have searched many sparse matrix libraries on the internet and tested some of them. I found that each of them only supported very few operations(many of them can only solve linear algebraic equations and do matrix-vector multiplication) .Finally I found one named SparseLib++. It didn't support many operations, either.So I added a lot of basic matrix operations. Now it works. However, I just heard that SparseLib++ was too old and not fast. But my project is based on SparseLib++ and I have spent a lot of work on SparseLib++. So I am wondering whether to try another sparse matrix library or not.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/ has a lot of built in linear algebra and ca distribute matrices over a cluster when your data gets big. There's also an active following on https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ when you have technical questions. The downside is that the learning curve is a bit steep.

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone recommend some libraries for me?

- [A quite detailed list with comparisons](http://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/la-sw.html)
- [Recommendations for a usable, fast C++ matrix library?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/351)
- [What are the most widely used C++ vector/matrix math/linear algebra
  libraries, and their cost and benefit tradeoffs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1380371/341970)

> If you recommend, please tell me the advantages and disadvantages of it, and the reason why you recommend it.

When it comes to large-scale sparse stuff, I personally use the Harwell Subroutine library. It's written in Fortran and it is a pain to interface it with C++. Nevertheless, I use it because it is robust and fast.

Comment: HSL is not open source, so I can't add my own matrix operations into it conveninently. But the list you gave is very detailed.Thank you! By the way, I still cannot decide which library to choose after reading the list...

Comment: **HSL is open-source** but with a restrictive license which may not be appropriate for you. What operations do you need that HSL cannot do? Keep in mind that HSL is written in FORTRAN and using it from C++ is a major pain.

Comment: For example, I need to get the inverse of 3*3 block diagonal of a 3n*3n matrix. That is to say, for a 3n*3n matrix A, A can be decomposed like this: A=D-L-U, where D is 3*3 block diagonal. I need to compute the inverse of D. I guess that  HSL can't do this efficiently. However, since you have pointed out that HSL is written in FORTRAN, I think I should try another library.

Comment: @LiMing Yes, this sounds like a special algorithm. Well, good luck anyway!

Answer (score 1):

[Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSparse.html#TutorialSparseFilling) library has good support for spars matrix manipulation, and the most appealing feature is that its style is like Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

[Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm) would be a good place to start. The libraries are free, well supported, well documented, fast and portable.