# Initializing diagonal matrix in opencv, C++

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I am writing smoothing spline in C++ using opencv.

I need to use sparse matrix (like in MATLAB), i.e. large matrix which consists of zeros and a few non-zero diagonals. I use `Mat` matrices for this purpose, because I want to be able to multiply them, transpose them, etc.

Is there exist some elegant way to initialize such matrix, without processing it element after element?

There is a function called `Mat::diag`, but this creates a column matrix, it is not what I need. Is it possible to convert this to `normal` matrix? The most similar thing to what I need is `Mat::eye`, but I need to initialize more than one diagonal, in addition, I have different numbers in same diagonal, so I cannot use `Mat::eye`.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean with _more than one diagonal_? Do you have the _different numbers in same diagonal_ stored in a vector or something? Could you edit adding how final matrix should look?

Comment: For example, matrix 3X3 has one "general" diagonal of length 3, two diagolals of length 2 each one - above and below the main diagonal, etc. And, yes, I may have different numbers in same diagonal.

Comment: well, you can set different "diagonals" creating "small" submatrices using Mat::eye to generate each one, and then sum each diagonal matrix on a zero initialized matrix with the actual size. If you need to set also different values, you need to set them manually. You can always wrap this all in a single function. If you provide the data structures (vector or whatever) that contain your data, and the final result you are expecting, it'll be much easier to provide a solution

Comment: Since tou mentioned matlab, do you know how to do it in Matlab? If so, provide an example that will be easily ported to OpenCV.

Comment: opencv has a sparse matrix class too. But not sure whether it has multuiplications etc implemented

Answer (score 1):

I solved myself: :)

```
Mat B = Mat::zeros(3, 3, CV_8UC1);
Mat C = B.diag(0);
C.at<unsigned char>(0) = 64;
C.at<unsigned char>(1) = 64;
C.at<unsigned char>(2) = 64;
```

`Mat::diag` is dynamic, so it works.

Comment: That's not what you asked. You can simply use `Mat A = Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_8UC1)*64;` to get that.

Comment: Mat B = Mat::zeros(3, 3, CV_8UC1);
Mat C = B.diag(0);
C.at<unsigned char>(0) = 64;
C.at<unsigned char>(1) = 64;
C.at<unsigned char>(2) = 64;

Comment: Is that really better than just doing `B.at<unsigned char>(0,0) = 64;`, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize with `Mat::eye` and multiply by a 1 by N dimensional matrix containing the diagonal values you want. (Or just set them manually.) If your matrix is large enough that these operations take a significant amount of time you should **not** be using `Mat` which is not optimized for sparse matrices.

If your matrices are large enough that the above operations are slow, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241227/sparse-matrix-library-for-c).