# Is it possible to make a template function that is a friend to a bunch of similar classes?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a bunch of extremely similar matrix classes with only difference in their size.

For example:

```
class clrMatrix8x8
{
public:
    clrMatrix8x8();
    clrMatrix8x8(const clrMatrix8x8&);
    ~clrMatrix8x8();

    void fill(int);

    static clrMatrix8x8 elemAdd(const clrMatrix8x8&, const clrMatrix8x8&);
    static clrMatrix8x8 elemSubstr(const clrMatrix8x8&, const clrMatrix8x8&);
    static clrMatrix8x8 elemMult(const clrMatrix8x8&, const clrMatrix8x8&);
    static clrMatrix8x8 scalMult(const clrMatrix8x8&, int);
    static clrMatrix8x8 elemDiv(const clrMatrix8x8&, const clrMatrix8x8&);
    static clrMatrix8x8 scalDiv(const clrMatrix8x8&, int);

    int& operator()(size_t, size_t);
    clrMatrix8x8& operator=(const clrMatrix8x8&);
private:
    std::array<std::array<int, 8>, 8> content;
};
```

There are classes for 16x16, 32x32 and so on. All of them work the same as well as their functions. For `clrMatrix8x8`, `elemAdd` function is:

```
clrMatrix8x8 clrMatrix8x8::elemAdd(const clrMatrix8x8& first_, const clrMatrix8x8& second_)
{
    clrMatrix8x8 temp(first_);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < temp.content.size(); i++)
    {
        std::transform(temp.content[i].begin(), temp.content[i].end(), second_.content[i].begin(),
            temp.content[i].begin(), std::plus<int>());
    }
    return temp;
}
```

The only difference between this function and the same function for other matrix is class names.

Since it doesn't feel good to have 5 similar implementations of each function for each class I thought it was possible to make a template function which is friend to all the matrix classes. So, I put `template<class T> friend T elemAdd_text(const T&, const T&);` in `Matrix.h` as well as inside 16x16 and 8x8 matrix classes declarations and

```
template<class T>
T elemAdd_test(const T& ad, const T& af)
{
    T temp(ad);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++)
    {
        std::transform(temp.content[i].begin(), temp.content[i].end(), af.content[i].begin(),
            temp.content[i].begin(), std::plus<int>());
    }
    return temp;
}
```

in `Matrix.cpp` to test this out, but when I call this function in `main()` like this: `some8x8matrixVariable = elemAdd_test(other8x8matrix_1, other8x8matrix_2);` it gets LNK2001 "unresolved external symbol" error. What am I doing wrong?

I know it would be much easier to just use a `vector` of `vector`s, I tested that and `array`-based matrix worked ~6 times faster, and I need as much performance as possible.

Comment: Isn't what you're describing just inheritance? You might be digging too deep into c++-specific metaprogramming craziness, this is a problem best solved by basic OOP I think. Make a parent `Matrix` class with each variation as subclasses with a getter for the size.

Comment: Depending on your objective. You could consider how the likes of [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) does it or even just use it for your project. Here is a whole [list of libs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380371/what-are-the-most-widely-used-c-vector-matrix-math-linear-algebra-libraries-a#answer-1380432)

Comment: Instead of using template friend functions, why not make the whole class a template class?

Comment: @Klaycon, :/, looks like a solution, I think I'll try that, thanks.